# The language of all base-10 integers that are multiples of 9

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

If I want to represent all the base 10 integers that are multiples of 9 as a language how do I do so?

Alphabets are finite sets.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  $10^9, 10^{18}, \dots$ is not the list of integers that are multiples of 10.  It's not clear what you mean by "write an alphabet for it".  Perhaps you want to determine whether the language is regular and/or find a regexp or NFA for the language?  Can you think about how to edit your question to show more clearly what you are asking and what you understand?  Are you asking how to represent an integer like 3478 as a string?  This is a four-character string, containing the characters 3, 4, 7, 8 in order -- is that really what you're asking?

Comment: @D.W. You're right, let me try to explain better. I guess I am wanting to represent all base-10 positive integers that are a multiple of 9 as a regular language, and then write an alphabet for that. But just step one for now (just the language bit).

Comment: What do you mean by "represent"? I don't see what you are asking, and apparently your edits have been completely changing the question (seeing as David's well-intentioned answer does not fit anymore). Please make sure you know what your quesiton is *before* posting so you don't waste people's time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the definitions.  An alphabet is a finite set of characters (or "symbols") that are used to write strings; a string is a sequence of characters from some alphabet.

When you write numbers down, you write them as a sequence of symbols.  What symbols are those?  That's your alphabet.